# Why does BuyExecution not support JIT fees in XCM v3?

Tags: polkadot, xcm, xcmv3

The [XCM v3 implementation of `BuyExecution`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/83c5b4164ded0b878df3cae61c832d0137ab87e5/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L685-L690) does not make use of the [newly introduced JIT fees](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/83c5b4164ded0b878df3cae61c832d0137ab87e5/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L930) withdrawal. (e.g. used via `take_fee` [here in `ExportMessage`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/83c5b4164ded0b878df3cae61c832d0137ab87e5/xcm/xcm-executor/src/lib.rs#L846))

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the one responsible for paying the fees isn't always necessarily the origin.

Recall that you can fill up the holding register with assets via a couple of instructions, they are:

- `WithdrawAsset`
- `ReceiveTeleportedAsset`
- `ReserveAssetDeposited`
- `ClaimAsset`

Of which the only instruction that takes fees from the origin is `WithdrawAsset`. For all the other instructions listed, it is most often not the case that the asset being put into the holding register belongs to the origin.